# How to sum up weights of equal rows of a matrix without using 'for loops'

Tags: matlab

I have a m x n matrix 'A' with a m x 1 vector of Weights corresponding to A. I have used 'unique' to find the unique matrix and to find IA and IC. How I can sum up the weights of equal rows in A in a faster way than using two 'for loops'? So far, I have

```
[Dis_Good_path,IA,IC]=unique(Good_path,'rows','stable'); 
for i=1:length(IA) % Summing up the weights corresponding to equal paths 
   Dis_R2(i)=0;
   for j=1:length(IC) 
      if IA(i)==IC(j) 
         Dis_R2(i)= Dis_R2(i)+R2(j); 
      end 
   end 
end
```

Comment: It would be probably useful if you post your code and we try to help you to optimize it

Comment: What are `iA` and `IC^?  What does it mean to "sum up the weights of equal rows in A"?

Comment: [Dis_Good_path,IA,IC]=unique(Good_path,'rows','stable');
        for i=1:length(IA)  % Summing up the weights corresponding to equal paths
            Dis_R2(i)=0;

Comment: for j=1:length(IC)
                if IA(i)==IC(j)
                    Dis_R2(i)= Dis_R2(i)+R2(j);
                end
            end
        end

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately to include the code. Comments are **not the right place for code**.

Comment: @DavoudGhodsi I think you code is doing something different due to IA(i)==IC(j) comparison

Comment: IT is summing up the weights, taken from R2 weight vector,  of equal rows of Good_path matrix through comparing IC elements with the unique elements of IA. This comparison find the indices of the IC elements which are equal to each of IA elements.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with one loop less would look like this :)

```
[Dis_Good_path,ia,ic]=unique(Good_path,'rows','stable');
Dis_R2 = R2(ia);
rIA = setxor(ia,1:size(Good_path,1));
rIC = ic(rIA);
for i = 1:numel(rIC)
   Dis_R2(rIC(i)) = Dis_R2(rIC(i)) + R2(rIA(i));
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is like this but your code doesn't sum up the weights correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without even one loop? because still it is very time consuming for large matrices.